# Where is JAR file from spring boot's build progress in docker linux environment...?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle

First, I'll explain my situation.

I have a spring boot project in the aws cloud9 environment on Github.

This spring boot project currently does not have a build folder.

The approximate project structure is as follows.

```
eks-workspace
 
  spring-backend

    gradle

    infra

    src

    bulid.gradle.kts

    Dockerfile

    gradlew

    gradlew.bat

    settings.gradle.kts
```

In this situation, I wrote the Dockerfile like this.

```
// Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle.kts .
COPY settings.gradle.kts .
COPY src src

RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew bootJar

COPY example.jar .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/example"]
```

In order to see where the jar file was stored during the docker build process, I ran the "RUN ls -al" command and confirmed that the jar file was stored in "/build/libs/example.jar".

However, when I executed the instruction "COPY/bulid/libs/example.jar /" in Dockerfile, "COPY failed: file not found in build context or expanded by.docerignore: stat example.jar: file does not exist" occurred.

I don't think it's an error where the file doesn't exist because I didn't create a separate .dockerignore file, but I don't know where the jar file is during the build process.

Comment: `COPY` copies a file from outside the Docker build environment into the image.  Do you need to `RUN cp` instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze OMG... your answer was perfectly correct... Thanks a lot!!